# Designing a job queuing system where only one job per user can be processed by workers any given time

Tags: architecture, worker, beanstalkd, job-queue

I've a single job queue with multiple workers watching this queue. (each job corresponds to a single user). There might be multiple jobs per user in the queue at any given time.

I do not want my workers to process more than 1 job per user at any given time. A user's job should be picked by a worker only if there is no other worker processing this user at that time. In case a user's job is being processed by a worker, I would also want the next user job to be picked immediately as soon as it is finished.

I want to keep my workers user agnostic (ie, any worker should be able to process any user's job). This would help me to scale horizontally.

How should I go about it? I though about creating separate queues per user but then the workers would have to watch a huge number of queues and might waste resources. I'm using beanstalkd as a queue server right now.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that restriction of processing exactly one job per user may lead to extreme delays of processing jobs for other users. Consider a scenario when your queue contains large sequential number of jobs for user1 followed by large sequential number of jobs for user2 and so on. As a result of your proposed architecture, you will have to drain your queue of user1 jobs **first** and only then user2 jobs will begin to process, leaving user3 to wait for a long time...

You may be able to relieve the situation by introducing multiple queues (still not one per user) and queuing up your work in round-robin fashion, but as you can see this is still not 100% reliable.

However, if you truly want to guarantee this requirement with one (or few) queues, I would actually advise to use some kind of shared locking mechanism ([memcached](https://github.com/evan/memcached) for example) to maintain locks per user while job for that user is being processed. 
[This article](http://www.regexprn.com/2010/05/using-memcached-as-distributed-locking.html) describes how, and there are [gems](https://github.com/mavenlink/morlock) to do that.
Then you can use the following algorithm:

```
job = @beanstalkd.reserve
user_id = job.body["user_id"]
if (get_lock_for(user_id)
  # process job
  # ....
  job.delete
end
```